# filtering array in range of array time and time now javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, time, filter

i get some trouble when i try to filtering time now in array time, i have code like this ;

```js
  var timeNow = "07";
    var timeShift = ["08","10","12","14","16","18","20","22","00","02","04","06"];
    var newData =[];
    for(var data of timeShift){
      if(data >= timeNow){
         newData.push(data);
        }
    }
    console.log(newData[0]); // output 08
```

the problem is output not same with my expectation. 
i want : 
 if **timeNow** is 08, **timeShift** output(selected) is 08,
 if **timeNow** is 07, **timeShift** output(selected) is 06, 
if **timeNow** is 09, **timeShift** output(selected) is 08, 
if **timeNow** is 23, **timeShift** output(selected) is 22,
. . . .  . . . continued as the structural of data **timeNow** and **timeShift** like my expectation in there.

How can i fix the problem ? 
 Please Help me.
Thank you :)

Comment: do you want only a single value?

Comment: yes, its helpful for me :) @NinaScholz

Comment: what do you mean by 'output not same with my exception'? Just want to understand your question better!

Comment: @alokstar okay, im sorry , the mean is expectation not exception, my english is bad. :) hehe

Comment: the main problem is, you have string, which represents numbers, but you do not have this relation in it. even the 24 h system is not mentioned here.

Comment: @NinaScholz you can convert it into the string, have an problem in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the closest single value which is less or equal to than the given one, you need just a small update to your code:

```js
function getTime(timeNow) {
var timeShift = ["08", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "00", "02", "04", "06"];
var newTime = '00';
for (var data of timeShift)
  if (data <= timeNow && data >= newTime)
    newTime = data;

return newTime;
}

console.log(getTime('08'));
console.log(getTime('07'));
console.log(getTime('09'));
console.log(getTime('23'));
```

Comment: yes alright. Thats same with my expectation. Thanks you sir @KoshVery. its helpful for me :)

Comment: @Raffikbojjes, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the values by taking the numericak value for comparing and a value decremented by one for checking.

```js
const getN = s => parseInt(s, 10),
      check = (strong, weak) => strong === weak -1 || strong === weak;
  
var timeNow = "07",
    timeShift = ["08","10","12","14","16","18","20","22","00","02","04","06"],
    result = timeShift.filter(s => check(getN(s), getN(timeNow)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: if timeNow i change to '09' the return index of array its not '08', but the return is '10 @NinaSchols

Comment: okay its alright. it work clearly,  thanks before it :) @NinaSchols

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the highest value less than or equal to now. You can accomplish this with a combination of `filter` (to first filter values from `timeShift` that are less than or equal to your target) and `reduce` (to find the maximum of those filtered values):

```js
var timeShift = ["08", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "00", "02", "04", "06"];

function highestUnder(now) {
  now = parseInt(now);
  return timeShift.filter(t => parseInt(t) <= now)
                  .reduce((a, c) => parseInt(c) > parseInt(a) ? c : a);
}

console.log(highestUnder("08"));
console.log(highestUnder("07"));
console.log(highestUnder("09"));
console.log(highestUnder("23"));
```

Comment: i want result one values which is in the data array of 'timeShift'.

Comment: @Raffikbojjes yes I believe that function is returning one value (you can run the code snippet to check).

Comment: okay sir. its work clearly. Iam sorry, im not check your code carefully. thank you before it :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is, once you have newData array you can just find closest number to 'timeNow' variable in this array. This is probably not efficient but should give you the desired output.
Adding following should do the trick:

```
var closest = newData.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: Yes alright, thats the point. but should i create a new variable to store the closest number to 'timeNow' variable in the array ? or just like filtering the data and add some logic if ?

Comment: Its your choice how you want to process the data further. One of the example can be the added code!

Comment: okay sir. Its work so fine. Same with my expectation. Thank you before it :)